# How to prevent \baselinestretch from affecting the math mode?

Tags: equations, line-spacing

Changing `\baselinestretch` will affect the distance between two adjacent rows. How to avoid this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper,vmargin=15mm,hmargin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \begin{equation}
        \tag{Trivial Matrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
            1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
            1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
        \end{pmatrix}
        \label{eqn:matrix}
    \end{equation}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{2}
\everydisplay{\def\arraystretch{0.5}}
```

However, you should use package `setspace` for setting the baselinewidth